# Custom shortcut OSX

Tags: macos, high-sierra, preview

I'd like to change the shortcut to hand tool in preview app.

The link below indicates that it can be done, if I know the name of the operation?
[Changing the shortcut for highlighting text in Preview](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208638/changing-the-shortcut-for-highlighting-text-in-preview)

Worth noting, I'd like the short cut to be a mouse click and scroll rather than keyboard.

If possible, how do I find the correct name for hand tool, so that I can change Alt+space to something else, and where do I go to make a mouse command?

Alternate solutions are welcome.

Comment: Why do you need to activate the hand tool with the scroll function of your mouse? All the hand tool does is move the page, which is what scroll does anyway.

Answer (score 0):

No. The linked article shows that key commands can be assigned to **menu items**. There doesn't seem to be a menu item for the Hand tool.

If the command has a menu item, then you can add a key command to it. You can't add mouse clicks using the Keyboard shortcuts.

You may have to use a third-party macro app, like [Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/), which will allow you to configure various inputs to various actions.